# Unknown column 'userpass' in 'field list'

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, mysqladmin

I'm working on the following project: http://lpmj.net/20.php

I've made several entries into phpMyadmin and am getting used to making the mySQL and php correspond, but with this error i have no idea what the code is asking for.

This is the error i'm recieving:

> Unknown column 'userpass' in 'field list'

Any help what this is indicating would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show the query and database structure? That error occurs when you are trying to select from a column that doesn't exist.

Comment: can you post your `PHP` code which connectes the DB?

Comment: there is likely a mismatched apostrophe in your query. I would do a <?php var_dump($myqryhere); ?> to see what the queries you have are actually doing, and likely there is a field without any content, or the content is not escaped correctly (contains a comma). This makes the query unable to find the field it it looking for.

Comment: The error message is self explanatory, you'll need to provide a code snippet in order for anyone to offer a solution to your overall problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This means that your field-list — the stuff right after the word `SELECT` — refers to a column named `userpass`, but that that column doesn't exist in the table(s) you're selecting from. For example, maybe your query looks like this:

```
SELECT userpass FROM foo;
```

when it should actually look like one of these:

```
SELECT userpass FROM bar;  -- was looking in the wrong table
SELECT user_pass FROM foo; -- mistyped the name of the column
```

Answer (score 3):

It means `userpass` does not exist. Check your spelling and make sure it does in fact exist